# How to select elements with the same name from nested list with purrr?

Tags: r, purrr

```
require(purrr)

list <- list( 
  node = list(a = list(y = 1, t = 1), b = list(y = 1, t = 2)),
  node = list(a = list(y = 1, t = 3), b = list(y = 1, t = 4)))
```

How to select all "t" values with purrr?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `modify_depth` for this if you know what level you want to pull the information out of.

You want to pull `t` out for the nested lists, which is level 2.

```
modify_depth(list, 2, "t")

$node
$node$a
[1] 1

$node$b
[1] 2


$node
$node$a
[1] 3

$node$b
[1] 4
```

The *purrr* `modify` family of functions returns an object of the same type as the input, so you'd need to `unlist` to get a vector instead of a list.

Comment: Nice. Is this `base R` or package-dependent?

Comment: This is from *purrr*

Answer (score 4):

Here are some ideas using functions from `purrr`. Thanks for the great suggestions from @cderv.

Here is the first one. The use of `pluck` is similar to `$`.

```
list %>% flatten() %>% transpose() %>% pluck("t")
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$a
[1] 3

$b
[1] 4
```

Here is the second one.

```
list %>% flatten() %>% map("t") 
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] 2

$a
[1] 3

$b
[1] 4
```

Finally, if we want a vector, we can use `map_dbl` if we know the elements in `t` are all numeric.

```
list %>% flatten() %>% map_dbl("t")
a b a b 
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: to stay full `purrr` funciton, you can use `pluck` instead of `\`$\`()` : `list_ex %>% flatten() %>% transpose() %>% pluck("t")`

Comment: And you can do more concise as you do not need `transpose` : `list_ex %>% flatten() %>% map("t")` gives you the same result

Comment: @cderv Thank you. I will update my answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: Cool ! I used `list_ex` instead of `list` as I think is not a good practice to have the name as a fonction. Just for you to know.

Comment: @cderv I agree. `list` is a bad name because it is a reserved function name already.

Comment: @cderv Updates completes. Thanks again for your great comments.

Comment: Thank you for the reference in the answer! glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr::map`

```
map(list, ~map(.x, ~.x$t))
```

Output is still list of list

```
$node
$node$a
[1] 1

$node$b
[1] 2


$node
$node$a
[1] 3

$node$b
[1] 4

unlist
```

To convert to vector

```
unlist(map(list, ~map(.x, ~.x$t)))
```

Output

```
node.a node.b node.a node.b 
     1      2      3      4
```

Comment: `map(.x, ~.x$t)` can be write directly `map(.x, "t")`. you don't need anonymous function. if `.f` is a number or a character, it acts an an extractor function.

Comment: and instead of `unlist`, you can go full `purrr` with `map(list, ~map_dbl(.x, "t")) %>% flatten_dbl()` to have a similar result