# extract identically named vectors from nested lists, where the list names vary? Using purrr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have to work with some data that is in recursive lists like this (simplified reproducible example below):

```
groups
#> $group1
#> $group1$countries
#> [1] "USA" "JPN"
#> 
#> 
#> $group2
#> $group2$countries
#> [1] "AUS" "GBR"
```

Code for data input below:

```
chars <- c("USA", "JPN")
chars2 <- c("AUS", "GBR")

group1 <- list(countries = chars)
group2 <- list(countries = chars2)

groups <- list(group1 = group1, group2 = group2)
groups
```

I'm trying to work out how to extract the vectors that are in the lists, without manually having to write a line of code for each group. The code below works, but my example has a large number of groups (and the number of groups will change), so it would be great to work out how to extract all of the vectors in a more efficient manner. This is the brute force way, that works:

```
countries1 <- groups$group1$countries
countries2 <- groups$group2$countries
```

In the example, the bottom level vector I'm trying to extract is always called `countries`, but the lists they're contained in change name, varying only by numbering.

Would there be an easy purrr solution? Or tidyverse solution? Or other solution?

Comment: Will "countries" always be at the same depth within the list? Or could there be a varying number of levels between "groups" and "countries"?

Comment: It's always the same depth. Thank you.

Comment: I'm finding a few SO posts on extracting from nested lists: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46123987/5325862) uses `purrr` with more deeply nested data, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50711333/5325862), or with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50367666/5325862), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13016359/5325862). I'm not totally satisfied yours is *directly* a duplicate of any of those but they should help

Comment: @camille very helpful! I'll go through some of the links you've put above, and keep searching deeper, and if my question is a duplicate, I'll close this up.

Comment: what is countries was NOT at the same depth?  what then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some additional cases to your list

```
groups[["group3"]] <- list()
groups[["group4"]] <- list(foo = letters[1:2])
groups[["group5"]] <- list(foo = letters[1:2], countries = LETTERS[1:2])
```

Here's a function that maps any list to just the elements named "countries"; it returns `NULL` if there are no elements

```
fun = function(x)
    x[["countries"]]
```

Map your original list to contain just the elements you're interested in

```
interesting <- Map(fun, groups)
```

Then transform these into a data.frame using a combination of `unlist()` and `rep()`

```
df <- data.frame(
    country = unlist(interesting, use.names = FALSE),
    name = rep(names(interesting), lengths(interesting))
)
```

Alternatively, use tidy syntax, e.g.,

```
interesting %>% 
    tibble(group = names(.), value = .) %>% 
    unnest("value")
```

The output is

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  group  value
  <chr>  <chr>
1 group1 USA
2 group1 JPN
3 group2 AUS
4 group2 GBR
5 group5 A
6 group5 B
```

If there are additional problems parsing individual elements of `groups`, then modify `fun`, e.g.,

```
fun = function(x)
    as.character(x[["countries"]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This will put the output in a list which will handle any number of groups

```
countries <- unlist(groups, recursive = FALSE)
names(countries) <- sub("^\\w+(\\d+)\\.(\\w+)", "\\2\\1", names(countries), perl = TRUE)

> countries
$countries1
[1] "USA" "JPN"

$countries2
[1] "AUS" "GBR"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply transform your nested list to a `data.frame` and then `unnest` the country column.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
groups %>% 
  tibble(group = names(groups),
         country = .) %>% 
  unnest(country) %>% 
  unnest(country)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   group  country
#>   <chr>  <chr>  
#> 1 group1 USA    
#> 2 group1 JPN    
#> 3 group2 AUS    
#> 4 group2 GBR
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Since the countries are hidden 2 layers deep, you have to run `unnest` twice. Otherwise I think this is straightforward.

Comment: Your solution is just what I'm looking for! Unfortunately, I must have oversimplied my question, and also misunderstood the data structure of the lists I have to work with. Because when I run your solution on the real data, I get an error saying `All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:`. I believe the lists I have to work with have a user-defined aspect to their data structure. Do you know of a simple way to turn user-defined data structures into standard data structures? I tried `as.list()`. Also, `typeof(groups)` returned `list`. Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error and the data structure sounds like a normal list. Maybe you can share some of your real data? You could try `dput(head(groups))` and then copy the output. My guess would be that one or several elements in the list are somehow different.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to have each vector as a an object in you global environment a combination of purrr::map2/walk and list2env will work. In order to make this work, we have to give the country entries in the list individual names first, otherwise list2env just overwrites the same object over and over again.

```
library(purrr)
groups <- 
  map2(groups, 1:length(groups), ~setNames(.x, paste0(names(.x), .y)))
walk(groups, ~list2env(. , envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

This would create the exact same results you are describing in your question. I am not sure though, if it is the best solution for a smooth workflow, since I don't know where you are going with this.